Is it permissible to sell sexual aprodisiac I will be direct in which types
I would like to know if it is permissible to sell
Feminine health products
That helps makes a lady’s pubic part get tighter as some lose this by giving birth
Is it also permissible to sell products that helps them boost their libido many married women find it hard to be with their husband because they do not enjoy it
And is it permissible to sell products that aids lubrication it could be oral (swallowed) or inserted or rubbed on the part of the body
They are feminine health problems ladies face in their marriage and even husbands complain of which sometimes make husbands cheat is it permissible to sell
And additionally if it is
When some customers  buy and they are not married because it’s a business we can ask each person are you married
What do we do
Natural products like honey dates, cloves natural herbs etc are used in production
